# Picker changes selected index after it's been selected

Tags: xamarin.forms

I've bound a picker like this...

```
picker.ItemsSource = Enumerable.Range(0, 24).ToList();
```

When I select a value on the iPhone simulator, after the picker has slid away, it adds 4 to the selected index. e.g. the number goes from 2 -> 6!

It doesn't do this on an iPhone device.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit hard to debug with just the information here but you can try...

1. Creating another simulator (maybe try different versions as well) and see if the problem persists
2. Turn your computer off and on again... sometimes when my simulator bugs out and resetting the simulator doesn't work this seems to do it sometimes.
3. Check your code again for maybe there is some code that could explain this situation that is just overlooked? If it always adds 4 you can try looking for 4 in code
4. Try deleting your obj and bin folders and doing a clean rebuild
5. Check if you build settings are different for device and simulator